# How does apps like Instagram, uber, discord shows notification even if the app is closed

Tags: node.js, react-native, flutter, push-notification, react-native-push-notification

I want to shows push notification in my app , of which backend is done in NodeJS and mongodb, with io socket .

 Every where I just see is FCM for push notification. what can be an alternative to that.
How does apps like Instagram shows push notification

Answer (score 0):

To deliver push notifications to android phones, you need to use the official google api. This is firebase cloud messaging (FCM). You can send the messages from your backend to the FCM API.
For Apple devices it works similar, you can sent your messages directly to the Apple APNS API without FCM. But it is also possible to use FCM for iOS, but in reality the notifications will be delivered to the iOS devices from a apple server.

Comment: My app has chat app (one to one and group chat)  feature, hence it could got to hundreds of notifications per user. And i don’t want to use third party providers like FCM. I wanted if there's  a way to make the socket run in background even if the, app is killed from recent window.?

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to Google's firebase fcm push notification you can try to reach out to the onesignal notification service.

check out the official docs for more information:
https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/react-native-sdk-setup

Comment: My app has chat app (one to one and group chat)  feature, hence it could got to hundreds of notifications per user. And i don’t want to use third party providers like FCM. I wanted if there's  a way to make the socket run in background even if the, app is killed from recent window.?

Comment: for the check functionality, you also can use this library you only have to manage the online flag if the user is offline then send them a notification on new message

Comment: but is there a way to do with background service?

Comment: I cannot get the flow of implementation about how you are trying to implement the functionality.